# Characterizing when matrices are 'dissipative'

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, functional-equations, operator-norms

An $n$ by $n$ matrix A is said to be *dissipative* with respect to a norm $\|\cdot \|$ if for all $x$ and $t\geq 0$, we have $\|e^{At}x\|\leq\|x\|$. Two matrices $A$ and $B$ are said to be jointly dissipative if they are each dissipative with respect to the same norm.

Here $e^{At}$ is defined by

$$e^{At}:=\sum_{n=0}^{n=\infty}\frac{1}{n!}A^nt^n.$$

My question is the following: what are necessary and sufficient conditions (on $A$ and $B$) for the existence a norm for which $A$ and $B$ are jointly dissipative?

Of course depending on what we take $n$ to be, this question can be quite hard. If anyone has any particularly clever suggestions for an approach, or solutions to special cases ($n\geq 2$), I would love to hear from you.

Answer (score 6):

The discrete-time analogue -- there exists a norm in which $|A_1^nx|\leq |x|$, $|A_2^nx|\leq |x|$ for all $n\geq 1$ and $x \in\mathbb{R}^d$ --  is equivalent to the property that the semigroup generated by $A_1$ and $A_2$ is bounded. To see this we just define
$$|x|:=\sup_{n\geq 0} \|A_{i_n}\cdots A_{i_1}x\|$$
for all $x$. Determining whether or not this property holds is known to be an algorithmically undecidable problem by work of Blondel and Tsitsiklis.

There could easily be continuous-time analogues of these statements, but I'm not very familiar with that part of the literature.

Comment: I would say that the continuous analogue should be the same, but we need to involve the semigroup $S$ generated by all $\exp(At)$ and $\exp(Bt)$ with $t>0$. If this semigroup is unbounded, then the matrices are not jointly dissipative, otherwise one may define $\|x\|_S=\sup_{C\in S}\|Cx\|$.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been addressed in the infinite dimensional setting in the following paper:

*Máté Matolcsi*, [**On the relation of closed forms and Trotter’s product formula**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-1236(03)00075-2), *J. Funct. Anal.* **205** (2003), no. 2, 401--413.

Theorem 2 is of special interest here. If there are any practical consequences, I do not know.